# React native webview crash when playing youtube embed video

Tags: react-native, webview

When playing a video, playing a music app will crash.

Prompt SMS or phone sound will also crash

Looks like any system sound will cause a crash

I tried to upgrade to the latest version of react native and have the same problem.

please help me

```
import { WebView } from 'react-native';

@observer
export default class MyWebView extends Component<any>
{
    setPlay = (){
         this.setState({play: true})
    }
    render() {
        const uri = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/71pyOB4TPRE'
        let play = this.state.play
        return (
          <View >
            {!play ? <TouchableOpacity  onPress={this.setPlay}>
                <Image style={{ width: 40, height: 40 }} source={playerIcon} />
            </TouchableOpacity> : null}

            { play? 
            <View style={{width: 450, height:300}} >
                <WebView
                    source={{ uri: uri }}
                />
            </View> :null}
          </View>
        )
    }
}
```

If show webview directly, it won't crash

```
    render() {
        const uri = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/71pyOB4TPRE'
        let play = this.state.play
        return (
          <View >
            <View style={{width: 450, height:300}} >
                <WebView
                    source={{ uri: uri }}
                />
            </View>
          </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Android only

Comment: I added the code. The code is very simple. I am using version 0.58.5

Comment: What mobile device is this?

Comment: I found the reason for the error but still don't know why

Comment: Expo or ejected?

Comment: ejected @diogenesgg

Comment: andorid only @diogenesgg

Comment: Maybe it's related to this `mobx` module, which the `@observer` tag comes from. I wasn't able to reproduce your problem. I couldn't make the App build after installing `mobx` and `mobx-react`.

Comment: Any use of props state navigation.getParam will cause a crash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found a very stupid solution.
Add this code in entery file index.js

``` <View style={{ height:0 }}><WebView source={{ html: `` }} /></View> ```

Like this

```
import TabNavigator from './router'
const AppContainer = createAppContainer(TabNavigator)

export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        if( Platform.OS === 'ios' ){
            return <AppContainer />
        }

        return <React.Fragment>
            <View style={{ height:0 }}><WebView source={{ html: `` }} /></View>
            <AppContainer />
        </React.Fragment>
    }
}
```

I did not find a specific reason
But this works for me

Very strange, is it only I have this problem?